# Views Block origin link in breadcrumb

Tags: views, breadcrumbs

I've created a **views block**, which contains a list of same **node types**. The block is placed within another node on my page "**home >> blockpage**". When you now follow some link in the block view you will get a breadcrumb like "**home >> pageFromBlock**".
How to achieve a breadcrumb like "**home >> blockpage >> pageFromBlock**".

I am using drupal 7 with breadcrumb module and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by using these modules:

[Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)

> Many new features have been added including support for Views, Panels,
>   Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths, and a simple API that allows
>   contributed modules to enable custom breadcrumbs for module pages and
>   theme templates. These are implemented using optional, independent
>   submodules that depend on the main Custom Breadcrumbs module.

[Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site!
>
> Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for **any
>   page** with **any selection rules** and load **any entity** from the
>   URL!